# The variable communication consumption in matlab parallel computation

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, global-variables, broadcast, parfor

Here are my codes:

```
cell1 = cell(5,1);
parfor idx=1:numel(cell1)
    a = cell1{idx};
end
```

where the cell1 is with the message as below:`The whole array of struct is a broadcast variable. This may cost unnecessary communication overhead.`

I cannot understand the explanation:

> Explanation
>
> The specified variable appears inside a parfor loop
>   within different indexing expressions. Because the indices are
>   inconsistent across the uses of the array created by the parfor loop,
>   MATLAB sends the entire array to each worker, resulting in high data
>   communication overhead. For example, the following code elicits this
>   message for c, because there are two different indexing expressions
>   for it...

Does MATLAB ship the whole cell to every worker in the parallel pool?

Can I slice the cell and ship them to the workers myself?

Comment: I don't get that editor message with the same code in R2017b... which version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: @Wolfie Sorry I made a mistake, it should be `cell(5,1)`

Comment: OK, as I said I still can't reproduce your issue... What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: That code cannot produce that message - the message is apparently referring to a variable named `struct`. Please post a minimal reproduction that actually demonstrates the problem.